# Checkbox ng-model as variable from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have categories list with checkboxes. I need to set ng-model as variable from ng-repeat. Filter works fine when I set ng-model manually. I tried many solutions but no one works in this case.

My angular version is 1.4.3

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items>
   <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="'setFilter.' + item.category"></li>
</ul>

<span ng-repeat = "product in products | filter:setFilter.category></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items>
   <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="setFilter[item.category]"></li>
</ul>

<span ng-repeat = "product in products | filter:setFilter></span>
```

**Updates** :
 you cannot assign ng-model like these

```
ng-model="'setFilter.' + item.category"
```

I have updated your fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinthan93/Bw77D/562/)

Comment: make your question in plunkr. i will help

Comment: Ok i made my case in jsfiddle. Everything works fine. I need to parametrize [GENERE NAME HERE]. http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/560/ Thanks in advance. Angular version 1.4.3

Comment: I have updated these fiddler(http://jsfiddle.net/aravinthan93/Bw77D/562/). Is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, everything is ok. Thank you mate!